# IText 7 add text color with gradient

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Is it possible to add text with gradient color using itext 7+ ?

[image: like this]

I tried doing this but it didn't help

```
AbstractLinearGradientBuilder gradientBuilder = new LinearGradientBuilder()
            .setGradientVector(A6.getLeft(), A6.getLeft(), A6.getRight(), A6.getRight())
            .addColorStop(new GradientColorStop(COLOR_PURPLE.getColorValue()))
            .addColorStop(new GradientColorStop(COLOR_RED.getColorValue()));
BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage.Builder()
            .setLinearGradientBuilder(gradientBuilder)
            .build();
Text text = new Text(code);
text.setProperty(Property.BACKGROUND_IMAGE, List.of(backgroundImage));
```

also tried some libs for converting html to pdf, but can`t find any which recognized -webkit-background-clip and -webkit-text-fill-color tags